# How to remove the border around an image in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me to remove the border of this "Plus" image?

```
<div id="Drop Image and Advance Search" style="margin-left: 0px">
    <img id='downarrow' style='float: left;'
        border=none src=".\images\button_plus.gif"
        width="20" height="20"
        onclick="javascript:toggle();"> 
    <img id='uparrow'
        style='display: none; float: left;'
        border=none src=".\images\button_minus.gif"
        width="20" height="20"
        onclick="javascript:toggle();"> 
    <a href="javascript:toggle();"> <u><h4>Advance Search</h4></u></a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried border="0"? A google search will show you this

Comment: You need to add more information. We can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: yes tried that but it wont work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `border="0"` instead of `border=none`

Or better yet, since the border attribute is deprecated as of HTML 4.01 (source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img)), add a style

```
<img style="border:0" />
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that replicates your issue? Have you refreshed the page with Ctrl + F5?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img border="0" src=".\images\button_minus.gif" width="20" height="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css like

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Need to use `style="border:0"`

```
 <div id="Drop Image and Advance Search" style="margin-left: 0px">

        <img id='downarrow' style='float: left; border:0px;'
            src=".\images\button_plus.gif"
            width="20" height="20"
            onclick="javascript:toggle();"> 
        <img id='uparrow'
            style='display: none; float: left; border:0px;'
             src=".\images\button_minus.gif"
            width="20" height="20"
            onclick="javascript:toggle();"> 
            <a href="javascript:toggle();"> <u><h4>Advance Search</h4></u></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your other answer? And why did you only copy what I wrote in my answer to yours?